# How do I exclude a specific file, without excluding every file with an identical name?

Tags: textmate2

In TextMate 2's `.tm_properties` I can exclude a file with a line such as:

```
exclude = "{index.php}"
```

However I'd like to exclude such a file in a specific location, not every file with that name.

Obviously, trying `/index.php` or `\/index.php` didn't work.

Comment: .tm_properties can be created both in the user's folder and in the project folder. Is it enought to create the properties file in the folder, or do you have nested folders with indexes?

Comment: @GrahamPHeath yes, I have nested folders.